# No Thunderbird 45.x for 16.04LTS

Tags: thunderbird

Are there plans for Thunderbird to be updated to v45.x in the current Xenial repos?

I understand v38.x is a long term support branch, but will we move over to v45.x once 16.04.1 is released near the end of the month.

Comment: Just a small note that all releases of Thunderbird are long term support now. There were no major releases between the 38 and 45 versions. https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/releases/

Comment: I'd really like to see TB 45, too. Is there a PPA for it? The always suggested one (https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/thunderbird-next) only has the beta versions.